# WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall with filewatcher

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to Visual Basic and overall kind of new to coding in general.
Currently I work on a program which uses a filewatcher. But If I try this:

```
Public Class Form1

Private WithEvents fsw As IO.FileSystemWatcher

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    fsw = New IO.FileSystemWatcher("PATH")
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    '  fsw.Filter = "*.settings"

End Sub


Private Sub GetSettingsFromFile()    
Some Code
More Code
CheckBox1.Checked = True   
End Sub

Private Sub fsw_Changed(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles fsw.Changed
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = False 'this is set because the file is changed many times in rapid succesion so I need to stop the Filewatcher from going of 200x (anyone has a better idea to do this?)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
    GetSettingsFromFile()
    fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = True 'enabling it again
End Sub
End Class
```

But when I do this (trying to change anyhting in the form) I get this error:
System.InvalidOperationException (WinForms.IllegalCrossThreadCall)
It wont stop the program from working, but I want to understand what is wrong here and why the debugger is throwing this at me
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is being raised on a secondary thread.  Any changes to the UI must be made on the UI thread.  You need to marshal a method call to the UI thread and update the UI there.  Lots of information around on how to do that.  Here's an example:

```
Private Sub UpdateCheckBox1(checked As Boolean)
    If CheckBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        'We are on a secondary thread so marshal a method call to the UI thread.
        CheckBox1.Invoke(New Action(Of Boolean)(AddressOf UpdateCheckBox1), checked)
    Else
        'We are on the UI thread so update the control.
        CheckBox1.Checked = checked
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you simply call that method wherever you are and whatever thread you're on.  If you're already on the UI thread then the control will just be updated.  If you're on a secondary thread then the method will invoke itself a second time, this time on the UI thread, and the control will be updated in that second invocation.

Comment: Thank you, is there any other situation where I have to keep in mind that I'm on a different Thread? (I mean Call-wise?)

Comment: There are various situations where events are raised on secondary threads, e.g. `SerialPort.DataReceived`, and various situations where you will have purposely executed something on a secondary thread, e.g. using a `BackgroundWorker` or `Task`. You'll get a feel for it in time but if you ever get that message about an illegal cross-thread call, you know that you're trying to access a control from other than the UI thread and the solution is basically as above. Check this out for more info: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads